# How to dynamically update/set a sub attribute of a Collection in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I would like to specify in my code which attribute to set/update in a DB update dynamically. Something like this:

```
var fieldname = "firstname"
var name = "loomi"
Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id},
                    {$set:{"profile."+fieldname: name}})
```

(profile[fieldname] does not work btw.)

The result of the above should do the same as this:

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id},
                       {$set:{"profile.firstname": "loomi"}})
```

How can I achieve this in a neat way, please? (Without getting the whole object doing manipulations and sending the whole object back.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't currently define variable keys within an object literal. You'll instead have to build the object, then pass it:

```
var $set = {};
$set['profile.' + fieldname] = name;
Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id}, { $set: $set });
```

---

[Update]

ECMAScript 6 has defined support for [computed keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) within object literals/initializers.

So, with an [ES6-compatible engine](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), this can now be written as:

```
Meteor.users.update(
    { _id: Meteor.user()._id },
    { $set: { ['profile.' + fieldname]: name } }
);
```

Comment: Meteor 1.2 now support ES6 (renamed ES2015) by default for new projects. Older projects can add support with `meteor add ecmascript`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
    var $set = {};
    $set['profile.fieldname'] = 'the name';
    Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id}, { $set: $set }, function(error){
        if(error)
            console.log(error.reason)
    });
```